# Как сделать сохранение логов приложения Python (используя logging) в отдельные файлы, разделяя их по сессии?

Tags: python, логирование

Существует большая программа, использующая модуль `logging` для логирования. Во время её работы в лог делается много записей, нужно как-нибудь заставить логгер сохранять лог в другой файл при следующем открытии приложения. Как можно переключить логгер на другой файл при следующем открытии программы, создавая новый файл при каждой сессии?

Comment: При запуске скрипта проверяете файл лога, инкрементируете на 1, пишите в этот новый файл

Comment: создавать файл с датой в имени включающей милисекнды. или еще интереснее time stamp

Comment: А как вы создаёте лог-файл сейчас? Вроде бы не должно быть проблемой подправлять путь к файлу на нужный

Comment: А зачем вам отдельные файлы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import logging, time, os

class AqLogger:

    def __init__(self, name):

        self.filenames = list()
        self.Logger = logging.getLogger(name)
        self.getFilename()
        
        self.Logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter("""{%(asctime)s} [%(name)s:%(levelname)s] [%(filename)s <%(lineno)s>: %(module)s.%(funcName)s] %(message)s""")
        handler = logging.FileHandler((r'{0}'.format(self.filenames[0])), 'a+', 'utf-8')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        self.Logger.addHandler(handler)

    def getFilename(self):
        self.filenames.append(str( 'log/' + (time.strftime("""%d.%m.%Y_%H%M%S""", (time.localtime())))  + '_AsQammLog.log'))
```

Comment: зачем так усложнять..)

Comment: @eri, почему бы и нет?

Comment: Одна строчка с basic_config же

Comment: С классом удобнее, ведь логгеров у меня несколько